# Jenkins Pipeline upgraded Pipeline: Supporting APIs getting error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins pipeline plugin, I upgraded Pipeline: Supporting APIs from 2.14 to 2.16.

After upgrading while executing below groovy script i am getting error:

```
currentBuild.displayName = 'xyz'

Error:

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.security.ACL.as(Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;)Lhudson/security/ACLContext;
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.setDisplayName(RunWrapper.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
```

Can someone suggest , looks to be compatibility issue with pipeline plugins